# dojo grid source

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dojo, dojox.grid

I want to use dojo grid with asp.net mvc but i don't know how the server side function must look like(parameters and return json).
All the samples i've seen use a file as a source for grid.
Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

You can use dojox.data.QueryReadStore for you grid. The server-side implementation should handle parameters: sort, start, count and filters. And result json should look like this:

```
{ numRows: "100", identifier: "id", items: [ { id: 1, value: "someValue" },...]}
```

You can find more information about QueryReadStore and link to basic server side implementation on PHP here: [QueryReadStore](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojox/data/QueryReadStore)